# What Groovy language feature uses Spock to implement its condition testing DSL?

Tags: spock

As a Kotlin/Java programmer who does not speak Groovy, I wonder what language feature the Spock framework uses for its "condition testing" or in other words, what is missing in Kotlin to archive the same. I'm referring to this

```
def test() {
  // ...
  then:
  foo == 3
  bar == "a"
}
```

My guess is that the code block with the assertions is passed as an argument to the function `then()` which somehow accesses the Groovy interpreter to run the block statement by statement so that it can check if the result is `true` before continuing with the next statement. Or is there a Groovy language feature that makes it easier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spock syntax is valid Groovy syntax. For example, `then:` is just a label. The way Spock works its magic is by - and I am going to simplify here - registering itself in the Groovy compiler in order to apply [AST (abstract syntax tree) transformations](https://groovy-lang.org/metaprogramming.html#developing-ast-xforms) on Spock specs.

Groovy compilation has several phases of AST transformations. Basically, developers can hook into each one of them, registering transformers. AFAIK, Spock only focuses on a single phase named `SEMANTIC_ANALYSIS`, see [here](https://github.com/spockframework/spock/blob/7fa3d62b965a879f8a698ff7126aaeaf0db461af/spock-core/src/main/java/org/spockframework/compiler/SpockTransform.java#L40-L41):

```java
@GroovyASTTransformation(phase = CompilePhase.SEMANTIC_ANALYSIS)
public class SpockTransform implements ASTTransformation {
  // ...
}
```

By transforming Groovy code into a way more sophisticated series of annotations, (nested) method calls and other language elements, it implements its magic and transforms the Spock DSL into something which can be executed in a JVM with Groovy runtime. If you are interested, just look in the *target/test-classes* directory of your Maven or Gradle Spock module and open some class files with a good decompiler like the one integrated in IntelliJ IDEA, called Fernflower. But do expect your head to explode when first looking at it. I only have taken a few cursory glances at it and am amazed, not pretending to even begin to understand most of it in depth. But hey - you asked, and I am replying.

I do not speak Kotlin, but it seems as if in Kotlin you mostly use [lambdas and extension functions](https://www.raywenderlich.com/2780058-domain-specific-languages-in-kotlin-getting-started) instead of AST transformations in order to create a DSL.

Comment: Good explanation, but the best way to see what is happening is to use the `Inspect AST` in the [Groovy Web Console](https://gwc-experiment.appspot.com/?gist=58f61cf36e112ff654041eeec8d11a98). There is also a conference talk about this topic https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FlAdrMThfx4 also https://dkublik.github.io/2017/02/27/the-magic-behind-the-spock.html

Comment: Great resources, @LeonardBrünings. I guess I also want to watch those two, as soon as I have time to.